# Settings lost after reboot

Tags: manjaro, settings

I run Manjaro since a lot of months now, and I tried this and that. After one of the last updates it happens, that after every reboot my xfce4 settings (window style, panel, composite settigns) are gone and I get the panel at the bottom of the screen again with modules i didn't configure.
Another user on the same PC doesn't have this problems.
I checked and reset all files to rw for me in my ~/.config/ folder.

Can someone give me a hint to the right log or anyone here how had this problem also?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in the past. While it's more of a work-around than a solution, you can trigger the saving of your settings by logging out before running a reboot or shutdown.

You should then be able to reboot as normal, and everything will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that didn't help. Still the same.